# Rename a value returned from a IN LIST statement

Tags: sql

I'm performing a sql statement that selects a few columns from the table but for one column the query performs a IN select that returns rows which contain the requested values. 
My problem is that typical users won't understand the values returned from the db so I want to rename the values so that they are returned (in a csv file) in the users understanding.  Anyone help me?

The relevant section is as follows:

```
Select a.attr1, a.attr2, b.attr1, b.attr2, b.attr3
From table a, table b
Where b.attr1 IN ('val.1', 'val.2', 'val.3', 'val.4', 'val.5')
```

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you have a join condition linking table a and table b? This is just going to return a cross product.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CASE` statement to format them appropriately, something like:

```
SELECT CASE a.attr1
    WHEN 'val.1' THEN 'myCustomVal1'
    WHEN 'val.2' THEN 'myCustomVal2'
    WHEN 'val.3' THEN 'myCustomVal3'
    WHEN 'val.4' THEN 'myCustomVal4'
    ELSE 'myCustomVal5'
    END,
 a.attr2, b.attr1, b.attr2, b.attr3
FROM table a, table b 
WHERE b.attr1 IN ('val.1', 'val.2', 'val.3', 'val.4', 'val.5')
```

Comment: Depends on how many possible display values there are.  If there's a large number of values, it may be better to just set up a separate table and join to it to pull display names, rather than writing huge queries every time the data needs to be retrieved.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses.  Helped immensely

Comment: @Puckhog No problems, glad we could help! If this was the answer you were looking for, please click the tick next to it to mark it as correct. Welcome to SO :)